# How do I set the prev of my first node to the next of my last node to create a circular doubly linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list, josephus

I am creating the Josephus problem using a circular doubly linked list. I am getting an Attribute error, which I assume is because my current_node (first node) does not have a .prev yet.

I understand that the prev of my first node should point to the next of my last node to create a circular doubly linked list.

Can someone guide me on whether I have correctly identified the error? If yes, how can I rectify it?

If not, then what are the other ways I can correct the error?

```
#Initialize the node
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
        
    def remove(self, n):
        print("Student " +str(n)+ " was removed")
        
class Circle:
# Initializing the DLL
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
#Inserting elements 2 to n in the dll              
    def insert_after(self, x, data):          
        y = Student(data) # make a new Node object.
        z = Student(data)
        z = x.next
        
        y.prev = x
        y.next = z
        x.next = y
        
        z.prev = y       
    
    def josephus_solution(self, dllist, n, k):
            no_of_active_nodes = n
            current_node = Student(1)
            #last_node = Student(n)
            #print(current_node.prev)
            for i in range(2, n + 1):
                dllist.insert_after(current_node, i)
                count = 0
            #print(current_node.data)
            while (current_node.next != current_node.prev):
                #print(current_node.next.prev)
                current_node = current_node.next
                count += 1
                #print(current_node.data)
                if (count == k):
                    current_node.remove(current_node.data)
                    current_node.prev.next = current_node.next
                    current_node.next.prev = current_node.prev
                    count = 0 
                    no_of_active_nodes -= 1
                    #print(no_of_active_nodes)
                if (no_of_active_nodes == 1):
                    print("Student" + str(current_node.data) + "Recieves the scholarship")
            return current_node.data

dllist = Circle()
n = 5 #int(input('Input number of people (n): '))
k = 2 #int(input('The nth person will be executed. Input k: '))
ans = dllist.josephus_solution(dllist, n, k)
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_24/3762059582.py in <module>
     54 n = 5 #int(input('Input number of people (n): '))
     55 k = 2 #int(input('The nth person will be executed. Input k: '))
---> 56 ans = dllist.josephus_solution(dllist, n, k)

/tmp/ipykernel_24/3762059582.py in josephus_solution(self, dllist, n, k)
     32             #print(current_node.prev)
     33             for i in range(2, n + 1):
---> 34                 dllist.insert_after(current_node, i)
     35                 count = 0
     36             #print(current_node.data)

/tmp/ipykernel_24/3762059582.py in insert_after(self, x, data)
     24         x.next = y
     25 
---> 26         z.prev = y
     27 
     28     def josephus_solution(self, dllist, n, k):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prev'
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct reason for the error is that `z` is `None` and your code can therefore not access any `prev` attribute of it in the line `z.prev = y`. The cause is that when the first node is created, its `prev` and `next` attributes are initialised to `None`, and when this node is passed as `x` argument to `insert_after`, then with `z = x.next` a `None` value is assigned to `z`.

There are several issues with your approach:

- In `insert_after` it makes no sense to call `Student` twice, since you want to insert one node, not two
- Although your `Circle` class has a `head` and a `tail` attribute, they are never used after their initialisation to `None`, so there is actually nothing in the Circle instance that helps you to maintain the list. You might as well define all methods on the `Student` class.
- The while condition in `josephus_solution` is probably intended to test that only one node remains in the list, but it actually verifies whether there are two left. Admittedly, this works when `current_node` is a node that was just deleted, but then the returned data is the data of the deleted node and not the remaining active node, and `current_node` is not a just-deleted node, then this condition will make the loop exit when it still has two active nodes.

Some other remarks:

- As you call `josephus_solution` as a method, it should not be necessary to also pass an instance as argument. `self` is already available to that method
- I would split the creation of the nodes into a separate -- generic -- method, and let `josephus_solution` work on an *existing* linked list.
- As in a circular list none of the `next` or `prev` attributes should ever be `None`, you'll make things easier when initialising them to `self` instead of `None`.
- The `remove` method should not be responsible for printing a message, but should on the other hand be responsible for rewiring the `prev` and `next` references. At any rate, there is no need for this method to get an argument, as it knows its own attributes through `self`.
- In the original Josephus problem, the first node is numbered as 1, so with k=2 the first node to remove is the one with number 2. Your code would first delete the one with number 3. To align with the original problem, move the `current_node = current_node.next` statement to be the *last* line in the body of the loop. This also helps to be sure that `current_node` is never a just-deleted node when the `while` condition is evaluated.
- As your `while` condition already takes care of when to stop, there should be no reason to keep track with a `no_of_active_nodes` variable.

There are more remarks to make, but these are what I believe the most important.

Here is a correction of your code, taking all of the above into account:

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        # Better make prev/next self references to avoid None:
        self.next = self
        self.prev = self
        
    def remove(self):
        # Perform the remove here
        self.prev.next = self.next
        self.next.prev = self.prev
        
    def insert(self, data):          
        # Should only create one node, not two
        node = Student(data)
        node.next = self
        node.prev = self.prev
        self.prev = node.prev.next = node

    # Handy method to create a circular list from values
    @classmethod
    def fromiterator(cls, iterator):
        head = cls(next(iterator))
        for value in iterator:
            head.insert(value)
        return head

    def josephus_solution(self, k):
        count = 0
        current_node = self
        while current_node.next is not current_node:  # This is how to test for 1 node
            count += 1
            if count == k:
                current_node.remove()  # No argument
                print("Student " +str(current_node.data) + " was removed")
                count = 0
            current_node = current_node.next # do this at the end of the iteration
            # No need to keep track of active nodes ...
        return current_node

# These are the parameters of the "original" problem (see Wikipedia)
n = 41
k = 3
dllist = Student.fromiterator(iter(range(1, n+1)))
# Don't pass the list as argument: it already is available as `self`
dllist = dllist.josephus_solution(k)
# Perform output in the main code, not inside method
print("Student " + str(dllist.data) + " recieves the scholarship")
```